# Query Fusion Table from JavaScript function in API v1

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to figure out how to use the new Fusion Table API v1 to query a table, from within a Javascript function. I want to be able to loop through the result, row by row, and do something else (in this case geocoding addresses) as I go.

I have the syntax for the query working OK. When I paste the http it into a browser it returns the correct result.

What I can’t figure out is how to make the request in the first place, and get the result where I can use it.

This post is close to what I’d like to do, but it uses the old API: http://www.reddmetrics.com/2011/08/10/fusion-tables-javascript-query-maps.html

```
function getData() {
    // Builds a Fusion Tables SQL query and hands the result to  dataHandler

    var queryUrlHead = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=';
    var queryUrlTail = '&key={my key}';
    Table = {my table id};

    // write your SQL as normal, then encode it
    var query = "SELECT Address, Name FROM " + Table + " LIMIT 5";
    var queryurl = encodeURI(queryUrlHead + query + queryUrlTail);

    var jqxhr = $.get(queryurl, dataHandler, "jsonp");
}
```

Maybe jquery is not needed with the new api?

Comment: So what I didn't know was that I need to enable jquery on my page using something like this: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
which access it via google!

Comment: One of the Google examples seems to invoke a callback function in the query itself, using the following: "&callback=handler". Does anyone had experience with this? How is it different from jquery? What are the advantages?

Comment: The callback=handler is used for [JSONP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about). You can either do this yourself or just let jQuery take care if it (jQuery uses JSONP as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided is okay, it works as expected (for me). I created a [jsFiddle to show you an example usage](http://jsfiddle.net/odi86/Sbt2P/) of it.

All you need to do it specify a function called `dataHandler` as this is what you tell jQuery to use as a callback. I.e. the result of the jQuery call is, that it calls the function you specified.

To get started I suggest to make you Fusion Table public. That way you can explore the usage of the API without having to worry about authentication etc.

```
function dataHandler(response) {
    console.log(response);
    //do something with the data using response.rows
}

function getData() {
    // Builds a Fusion Tables SQL query and hands the result to  dataHandler

    var queryUrlHead = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=';
    var queryUrlTail = '&key={my key}';
    Table = {my table id};

    // write your SQL as normal, then encode it
    var query = "SELECT Address, Name FROM " + Table + " LIMIT 5";
    var queryurl = encodeURI(queryUrlHead + query + queryUrlTail);

    var jqxhr = $.get(queryurl, dataHandler, "jsonp");
}
```

If you just use `console.log` to analyze the response you get from Fusion Tables (press <kbd>F12</kbd> in your browser to open the console/Developer Tools), you see that you get an object with a `columns` and a `rows` property, like that you can use the data the way you like. My example above simply prints a HTML table of the retrieved data.

In case your query has an error or is not accessible the `error` property is set with an according error message.

Comment: Thanks Odi, your example and jsFiddle itself was really helpful. Once I got things working there I realised the problem was with my page, which led me to (finally!) figure out that I needed to enable jquery (see my comment above).